# Is there a way to set the vertical scroll position of a page when at a specific break point?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I want the page to scroll down to an anchor id (or scroll down 1000px for example) if the browser/device width is resized to a certain break point (480px). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your scroll code inside `$(window).width()` condition if window is resized like

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    //write your scrolling code here
  }
})
```